# Finding a Hamiltonian cycle for the set of RGB colors?

Tags: graph-theory, hamiltonian-path

I'm consulting on an art project where a question about colors came up.

Consider the RGB colors as a graph.

- The nodes are ordered triples $(r, g, b)$ where each entry is an integer from $[0, 255]$.
- The distance between two nodes $(r, g, b)$ and $(r', g', b')$ is defined to be $|r - r'| + |g - g'| + |b - b'|$.
- There is an edge between two nodes if and only if the distance between them is $1$.

It's easy to find a Hamiltonian path for this graph - for a sketch I used the Grey code algorithm presented in [Guan 1998](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.119.1344&rep=rep1&type=pdf) - but this starts on **black** $(0, 0, 0)$ and ends on **white** $(255, 255, 255)$ so it is emphatically not a cycle.

For what it's worth, there are $8$ nodes of order $3$ and many ($387096 = 2 \cdot 3 \cdot 254 \cdot 254$) nodes of order $5$ (any triple containing exactly one of $0$ or $255$), so no Eulerian path is possible.

And it's easy to construct an Hamiltonian cycle using a variation on Guan for $4$-tuples - but unfortunately, color models only have three components.

Experimentation leads me to believe that such a cycle does not exist for $3$-tuples - if you try to work in two directions from **black**, you can make progress, but it seems you leave behind nodes that you won't ever be able to reach again - and my intuition is that some sort of parity argument should be possible, but an actual proof has eluded me.

Best result would be a construction of a Hamiltonian cycle for this graph.  Almost as good would be a maximal Hamiltonian subcycle.  An existence or nonexistence proof would be super too!

Comment: I claim that there are eight nodes of order $3$: The elements of $\{0, 255\}^3$

Comment: Urg, quite right!  Changed the text.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Such a cycle is possible, and I'll try to explain it to you:

First node in the graph will be (0,0,1), then we will go (0,0,2),(0,0,3),...,(0,0,255). Now we move to the next line and go (0,1,255),(0,1,254),(0,1,253),...,(0,1,1),(0,1,0). Next line - (0,2,0),(0,2,1),...,(0,2,255) and so on, on the last line we will go (0,255,255),(0,255,254),...,(0,255,0). Now we move one "plane" up, and backtrack - we go (1,255,0),(1,255,1),...,(1,255,255),(1,254,255),(1,254,254),...,(1,254,0),(1,253,0),... ..., (1,0,2),(1,0,1), and now we go one plane higher again, to (2,0,1) and we repeat what we did in 0-th plane, and in third plane we repeat what we did in first plane etc.

In the end, we will be at (255,0,1). Now we finish the cycle - we go (255,0,0),(254,0,0),(253,0,0),...,(1,0,0),(0,0,0).

I hope I was clear enough, if you have any more questions, ask in a comment.

Comment: The text could use some math-mode for the coordinates to improve readability +1 for the clever construction. It should work on any "cube"-graph with even side length.

Comment: Ah, so sorry for not getting to mark you correct before now, I had muted this thread in my inbox.

I'm finally using this today, almost three years later!

Comment: @Wojowu: I have an implementation here:  https://github.com/rec/christmas_lights/blob/master/christmas_lights/hamiltonian.py.  It took me a while to notice the key idea - that you skip from (1, 0, 1) to (2, 0, 1) instead of to (1, 0, 0), and similarly for 127 other odd-indexed faces, and then swoop down through (i, 0, 0) for the last 255.

Answer (score 8):

If you look at your vertices like lattice points you get something like this:

[image]

The subgraph $H$ which only contains the edges shown in the picture is a subgraph of the one you have. This graph is hamiltonian.

Proof: Consider only the top layer, call that graph $K$. That layer is hamiltonian whenever the number of points in the layer is even. 
$H$ is isomorphic to $K\square P_{256}$. And the [cartesian product](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graph_product) of a hamiltonian graph and a graph with a hamiltonian path is always hamiltonian.

Comment: Neat proof! Do you not mean that `H` is isomorphic to `K × P256`?  (Also, your cross-product sign doesn't seem to come out properly, and my encodings are correctly set...)

Comment: it should render as a square. yes, $H$ is isomorphic to $K\square P_{256}$

Comment: My bad - Cartesian products in graph theory are represented by ◻, not ×.  You learn something new every day!

Comment: I liked this answer a lot and upvoted it, but another one actually listed the points for such a cycle, and it got the nod for "most useful".